# Can I force knitr to interpret "\n" as an actual line feed in a string passed to an R function?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I am trying to use knitr to knit the following markdown to HTML from an .Rmd file using RStudio:

NOTE: This code will generate an error since you don't have access to the server I am querying, but the problematic HTML will still render and my question just concerns the formatting of the code in the HTML file - not the output from R.

````
SQL Code 

```{sql}
select 
  count(*) child_count
  ,year(eps_begin) year_plc
from vw_episodes
where eps_begin between '2009-01-01' and '2010-12-31'
  and fl_dur_7 = 0
group by 
  year(eps_begin)
```

R Code

```{r }
sqlQuery(cn, 
         "select 
                count(*) child_count
                ,year(eps_begin) year_plc
              from vw_episodes
              where eps_begin between '2009-01-01' and '2010-12-31'
                and fl_dur_7 = 0
              group by 
                year(eps_begin)")

```
````

My issue concerns the formatting of the R code when I knit to HTML. I would like the SQL code that is passed to the `sqlQuery()` function to be formatted similarly to the code that is produced in the SQL chunk. However, based on the HTML produced, knitr does not appear to be interpreting the `\n` in the string as an actual line feed - it's just interpreting it as text.

The resulting HTML (for the R chunk) looks like this:

```
<pre><code class="r">sqlQuery(cn, &quot;select \n                count(*) child_count\n                ,year(eps_begin) year_plc\n              from vw_episodes\n              where eps_begin between &#39;2009-01-01&#39; and &#39;2010-12-31&#39;\n                and fl_dur_7 = 0\n              group by \n                year(eps_begin)&quot;)
</code></pre>
```

When what I really want is something like this:

```
<pre><code class="r">sqlQuery(cn, 
    &quot;select
        count(*) child_count
        ,year(eps_begin) year_plc
    from vw_episodes
    where eps_begin between &#39;2009-01-01&#39; and &#39;2010-12-31&#39;     
        and fl_dur_7 = 0
    group by 
        year(eps_begin)&quot;)
</code></pre>
```

Any thoughts on how I can knit to HTML and still preserve the line feeds in strings that are passed to R functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** on 2017/09/21: the chunk option `tidy` defaults to `FALSE` in the current version of **knitr**, so it is no longer necessary to set it (there is no harm doing so, though).

---

That was due to the [default reformatting](http://yihui.name/knitr/options) of the code using the **formatR** package; you can turn it off by `tidy=FALSE`:

````
```{r tidy=FALSE}
````